# Solspace User - Register Form viewable to non superadmin

Tags: solspace-user, registration

So it states that using admin_register="yes" allows a designated member group (not necessarily a Super Admin) to register a member and see the register form when logged in.

See "This parameter allows users of member groups that are allowed to administrate members to view the Register form, and submit new user registrations on behalf of others. Using this parameter naturally will prevent the auto-login feature after registration from working (so the admin doesn't become logged in as the member they just created)."

Under Edit Member Group in the EE CP I have "Can administrate members accounts" set tp yes. What else needs to be enabled?
Thanks

Comment: I keep getting"You're currently logged in, and must be logged out to view this form."

Comment: What version of User and EE are you using? What does your `{exp:user:register}` form look like? Can you show it here? Are you logged in as a member of the member group that has "Can administrate members accounts" enabled?